# Point to new vmware view composer database

Tags: vmware-view

Small VDI deployment of about 80 desktops.  There was a point in time we used Composer for building our desktops.  Then, for the last few years we stopped using Composer in favor of Unidesk (now Citrix App Layer) for all desktop provisioning.  I left Composer installed on the vCenter server.

A month ago, I did a migration of our vCenter server from a Windows box to the VCSA.  And now, I'm needing to utilize Composer for the latest version of Citrix App Layer.

Of course, the VCSA doesn't have Composer built in, so I built a fresh Windows VM, installed Composer pointing it to a new database and then tried to edit the 'View Composer Server Settings' in the View Administrator -> View Configuration -> Servers -> vCenter servers dialog.

When I do this, the exact error message I receive reads:

*The View Composer server could not be changed. The View Composer database on the new server does not match the existing database. Make sure the new View Composer server uses the existing View Composer database or the existing View Composer configuration data is migrated to the new View Composer database.*

So I suspect it's complaining about the new, blank database I gave it.  I'm not at all worried about losing anything that might be in the old database (since all the active VM's are not using composer).  I'm a bit stuck though and curious how to get by this while using this fresh clean database and install.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2015112

This link solved my problem.  I needed to connect to the ADAM database to remove a bad pool that was tied to the old Composer server.

This allowed me to finally change the Composer server to the brand new one with the brand new database.